# c++ std::future running each function on a separate core

Tags: c++, multiprocessing, future

It's a realtime audio application running on a Quad Core Cortex A9 ARMv7 (Linux and gcc 4.8.2), and this is the part where the actual audio is being processed (by calling other functions) and is being sent to the audio driver:

```
struct STEREOOUT
{
    std::vector<float> L;
    std::vector<float> R;
};

STEREOOUT ProcessEngine(int e, unsigned int sf)
{
    STEREOOUT out;
    for (unsigned int s=0; s<sf; ++s)
    {
        float l, r; 
        engine[e]->Process(l, r);
        out.L.push_back(l);
        out.R.push_back(r);
    }
    return out;
}

// This is the main audio loop callback!
int AudioProcess(void *outputBuffer, unsigned int sampleFrames)
{
    float *buffer = (float*)outputBuffer;
    unsigned int s(0);

    STEREOOUT e0 = async(launch::async, &ProcessEngine, 0, sampleFrames).get();
    STEREOOUT e1 = async(launch::async, &ProcessEngine, 1, sampleFrames).get();

    for (; s<sampleFrames; ++s)
    {
        *buffer++ = e0.L[s] + e1.L[s];
        *buffer++ = e0.R[s] + e1.R[s];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How can I make sure that `e1` and `e2` are running with different affinities from the `main()` program and yet different between them? For example:

```
main() -> CPU0
e1 -> CPU1
e2 -> CPU2
```

My code, when compiled as you see it here, still appears to run on a single core. I need to two audio processing occupy two different cores in order to take advantage of the full power of a quad core processor. Am I just dreaming?

*P.S.: I know, I already posted similar questions in the past, but this time I can be more precise because I have a finished and working program now that I can use as an actual example.*

Comment: Your `main` depends on the results of `e0`  and `e1`, so there's no point in using a third thread for that. Since it needs to run only before and after `e0` and `e1` (but not in parallel with), `main` may as well use one of those two threads.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're calling `get` immediately after calling `std::async`, which will cause the program to *wait for the result to be available.* You need start *both* async tasks before you wait for them:

```
auto future1 = async(launch::async, &ProcessEngine, 0, sampleFrames);
auto future2 = async(launch::async, &ProcessEngine, 1, sampleFrames);

STEREOOUT e0 = future1.get();
STEREOOUT e1 = future2.get();
```

Comment: Are you sure that this way the two `ProcessEngine` functions will run in parallel and on separate cores? I'm asking because my code looked exactly like yours before, and I couldn't see any difference, so I changed it the way you see it now just because it looked tidier to me.

Comment: @MarkMiles: I think you don't understand what `.get` does. You call the first ` .get()` before the second ` launch`. That means you don't have two worker threads in parallel.

Comment: I accept this as an answer because it indeed makes a huge difference! I just can't believe that I *already* had the solution and it slipped away only because I changed a line in my code. At first I thought that it wasn't working because just one of the two thread was consuming too much CPU power. It wasn't due to the two thread workin serially, as I suspected... it was just one thread. Now I have tweaked the code for staying below the max CPU power, and I can actually run twice the same function without experiencing CPU overloads, this suggests that the multi-threading is really working.